# Parents class margin not forcing the child element

Tags: html, css

I have created one button with `float: left` align. Also, I added the style to the parent class `margin-top:50px` so that it will get the space from 50px from the top.

What I did, I just check inspect elements and hover to the parent class and it's displaying like below image

[Image link here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHKNz.png)

I want to know why margin:50px is displaying on the button?

Thanks in advance.

```css
body{margin: 0;padding: 0;}
.btn_click_now{padding:12px 30px;background-color:#007bff;color:#fff;font-size:18px;border-radius:05px;}
.pull-left{float:left;}
```

```html
 <div style="margin-top: 50px;">
 <div class="pull-left">
  <a href="#" class="btn_click_now">Buy Now</a>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: because padding-top/bottom on inline element are rendred outside

Comment: Thanks @TemaniAfif,This code is working for me display: inline-block;
display: -moz-inline-box;
-moz-box-orient: vertical;
vertical-align: top;
zoom: 1;
*display: inline;

Comment: well, you only need `display:inline-block` :)

Comment: @TemaniAfif, Thanks, It's working.